# IloNumVarArray Vs IloNumArray

Tags: arrays, optimization, cplex

I am working on a project in which the problem is solved using CPLEX. There are two classes IloNumVarArray and IloNumArray that I do not know their difference.

I really appreciate it if someone can explain this.

Thanks

Masoud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is very simple but very important.

The IloNumVarArray is used to hold the CPLEX modelling variables. These are the components used to construct your mathematical model. These variables have a domain or range of possible values (usually specified with upper and lower bounds) and they do not have values until after you have solved the problem with CPLEX.

IloNumArray is an array of simple variables in your programming language e.g. C++ doubles or ints (or the equivalents in C#, Java or whatever). These are used in your code which is creating your model and can appear as constants in your CPLEX model.